# Is there a way to pull just the Year out a VARCHAR datetime value?

Tags: date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sqldatatypes

I am working on a project, in Snowflake, that requires me to combine pest & weather data tables, but the opposing tables do not share a common column. My solution has been to create a view that extracts the year from the Pest Table dates, format ex.
CREATION_DATE: 03/26/2020 09:11:15 PM,
to match the YEAR column in the Weather tables, format ex.
DATEYEAR: 2021.
However, I have come to find that the dates in the pest report are VARCHAR as opposed to traditional date/datetime values. Is there a way to pull just the Year out the VARCHAR date value? Additional information: I cannot change the tables themselves, I will need to create a view that preserves all other columns and adds a new "DATEYEAR" column.

Comment: Yep this should be doable. Question - the date field that is a varchar in the `pest` table... is it `DD/MM/YYYY` or `MM/DD/YYYY` ? You've provided an example data 5/5/2021 which could be either.

Comment: Apologies, and great point, it's MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: Yes , we can and below is working example: create table test (dt string );
insert into test(dt) values ('01/04/2022');
Select dt, DATE_PART( year, dt::date) from test;

Answer (score 2):

Yes , we can and below is working example:

```
   create table test (dt string ); 
insert into test(dt) values ('01/04/2022'); 
Select dt, DATE_PART( year, dt::date) from test
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it easy, you can split the string into an array and take the third member of the array (using 2 since arrays are 0 based):

```
select strtok_to_array('03/26/2020', '/')[2]::int as MY_YEAR;
```

Comment: Would this code work applied to an entire column? Or is it best used for single instances? - I am trying to obtain just the year from every date in the column (~10,000 entries)

Comment: It would be fine to apply to an entire column. This is assuming the column is defined as varchar. If the column is defined as timestamp or date, you can use the DATE_PART function Anand references.